# parse html string with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML string from a Ajax loaded source.  I would like to get some attributes from an object (image) in this string, before I put the HTML into the document.

I've got something like:

```
$.ajax({  
        url: uri+'?js',  
        success: function(data) { 
            var htmlCode = $(data).html();  

            $('#otherObject').html(data);
        }  
    });
```

How can I get attributes (the `src` for example) from this HTML string?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure, but won't

```
$(data)
```

produce a jquery object with a DOM for that data, not connected anywhere? Or if it's already parsed as a DOM, you could just go $("#myImg", data), or whatever selector suits your needs.

**EDIT**
Rereading your question it appears your 'data' is already a DOM, which means you could just go (assuming there's only an img in your DOM, otherwise you'll need a more precise selector)

```
$("img", data).attr ("src")
```

if you want to access the src-attribute. If your data is just text, it would probably work to do

```
$("img", $(data)).attr ("src")
```

Comment: uuh, thanks for your answer! it's the solution :) i didn't see it. i wish you a good first april - and now i'll get in shame ;)

Comment: mhm, i've to regreat my comment. your example doens't work for ie (tested in version 7). i used "$(data)" - "data" - "$(data).html()" - nothing works. any suggestions?

Comment: $("img", $('<div><img src="http://www.example.com/test.jpg" /></div>')) worked in FF (haven't got IE7). Having just the IMG tag enclosed, or enclosed in just a body did NOT work, so perhaps it translates  to a single entity? Did you try $(data).attr () directly?

Comment: i tried $(data).attr() but this doesn't work either. i think it doesn't work in general with ie 7. i've to look for a workaround for exmaple to put the code into a hidden div, read the attribute and then show the code official in the document.

Comment: @Roe really thanks for your code... It was about 2 hours working on this and now i found the way (your code)... thanks again

Comment: Same again. Works like a charm.

Comment: It didn't work for me because I was trying to parse the whole page. This answer helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069953/854477

Answer (score 2):

MarvinS.-

Try:

```
$.ajax({  
        url: uri+'?js',  
        success: function(data) {  
                var imgAttr = $("img", data).attr('src'); 
                var htmlCode = $(data).html();
                $('#imgSrc').html(imgAttr);
                $('#fullHtmlOutput').html(htmlCode);
        }  
    });
```

This should load the whole html block from data into #fullHtmlOutput and the src of the image into #imgSrc.

Answer (score 1):

just add container element befor your img element just to be sure that your intersted element not the first one, tested in ie,ff

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note - as I had exactly this problem today, depending on your HTML jQuery may or may not parse it that well.  jQuery wouldn't parse my HTML into a correct DOM - on smaller XML compliant files it worked fine, but the HTML I had (that would render in a page) wouldn't parse when passed back to an Ajax callback.

In the end I simply searched manually in the string for the tag I wanted, not ideal but did work.

Comment: This could help if you are parsing whole page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069953/854477