# Can jquery functions be used to easily convert a string to a tree, manipulate a node, and convert back into a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

**Can jquery functions be used to easily convert a string to a tree, manipulate a node, and convert back into a string?**

original question: *How are jquery functions like selector and .html() used for string manipulation?*

**Updates:**

- I found related information at
  this question [parse html string with
  jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery)
- Ben Alman has an example
  of [replaceText](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) as a jquery addon
  which walks the tree and replaces
  text
- additional insight from this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string) for how to convert jquery objects to strings

First can jquery be used for the following? (I'll verify in a moment)

```
var b = $('<a href="#">bacon</a>').html();
```

does b === 'bacon', the answer is yes.

How can jQuery be used to perform string manipulation: (modified from [a sample highlighting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/120289#120289))

```
var key = 'bacon';
var str = '<a href="#">bacon</a><a href="#">tastes great</a>';
$(str).contents().each(function() {
  var node = this;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    var text = node.nodeValue;
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"),
            '<span class="Someclass">'+key+'</span>'
        ));
    //replace existing node value with text
});
// convert tree into string
```

the desired output is a string with the modified element(s):

```
str = '<a href="#"><span class="Someclass">bacon</span</a><a href="#">tastes great</a>';
```

Comment: I cast a rare downvote for this question, and I'd like to explain why. For your first example, you asked "does b === 'bacon'". You've already typed out the code - didn't you try it? A good question, I think, shows that you've done some work and explains your results thus far. That way, when someone finds it by search, they can learn something even from the question, and learn more from the answers. I don't mean to offend, and I hope that you see my point and grow more determined to keep the content on SO really great.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a browser feature, not a jQuery feature, and it is a String, not a Function.

Comment: cleaned up the question, was mangling my browser htmls with jquery's html method

Comment: Down vote understood Nathan, certainly if they make for better questions here. I'll continue to edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you want `.html()` instead:

```
var b = $('<a href="#">bacon</a>').html();
// Or,
var b = $('<a href="#">bacon</a>')[0].innerHTML;
```

As for the second example:

```
$('<a href="#">bacon</a>').html(function (i, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/(bacon)/g, '<span class="SomeClass">$1</span>');
});
```

Comment: I'd like to match to all text that's not in a tag. here's the fiddle I'm playing with http://jsfiddle.net/victusfate/uVczc/

Comment: Matching all text is different: `$(str).contents().each(function () {if (this.nodeType==3) $(this).wrap('<span class="SomeClass">');});`

Comment: @Mark, and there are a few things wrong with your jsfiddle. 1: Don't use document.write in conjunction with document.ready (which jsfiddle does automatically). Instead use `$('<div>' + str + '</div>').appendTo('body')`. 2: CSS uses `:`, not `=`. 3: You need to retrieve the value after `.html(function () ...)` with another `.html()`, e.g. `str = $(str).html(function () ...).html()`.

Comment: thanks, was fiddling with the css (poor memory for syntax). will swap the writes, and that last hint is much appreciated-> there can be several html elements in the strings I'm working with. also my fiddle jumped to /1 with an update, gotta reset that as the base version (still getting used to it)

Answer (score 2):

I would say "not exactly." The specific change that you're trying to make can be done as Box9 shows, but in terms of semantics, I'd say that you don't use jQuery for string manipulation, as far as I'm aware.

jQuery can be used to read and modify the DOM, and exists partly to make that process standard across browsers.

Once you've read the DOM, but before you update it, the part where you parse and change it can be done by manipulating strings, but the actual string manipulation will be in plain Javascript.

Comment: gotcha, should probably be using a dedicated string manipulation toolkit or javascript's defaults

Answer (score 1):

I have read this question and the corresponding comments & links a couple of times now and I am still not sure what the actual question is but...

> Can jquery functions be used to easily
>   convert a string to a tree, manipulate
>   a node, and convert back into a
>   string?

**Yes.**

The trick is using a wrapper element, and the jQuery html() and text() methods.
[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rrkng/2/) to show you what I mean.

Sometimes, you want to use text, to get all the text in an element without grabbing all the child elements like wrapping <b> or <i> tags. After it's a dom element you can use dom manipulation to append, add classes, modify attributes, and all that kind of stuff before casting it back into a string.

Is that the answer you were looking for?

*EDIT: Doh!  Got answered while I was typing*

Comment: If you're answer has less requirements I'll certainly pick it. I had imagined this type of manipulation would be a one or two liner without additional plugins. I was wrong. Noticed some issues with the solution I came up with.

Comment: To clarify I'm looking for specific text keys within html data that exists in a string format. Your fiddle accessed data from someClass and added an additional class, not quite what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using [Ben Alman's replaceText](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) and a [object to html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string/652771#652771) converter hack

```
function one() {
    var key = 'bacon';
    var str = '<a href="#">bacon nation</a> <a href="#">tastes good</a>';
    dump("before str contents: " + str);
    str = $(str).replaceText(new RegExp(key,"gi"),'<span class="SomeClass">' + key + '</span>');
    str = $('<div>').append($(str).clone()).remove().html();
    dump("after str contents: " + str);
}
```

and the desired output:

```
<a href="#"><span class="SomeClass">bacon</span> nation</a><a href="#">tastes good</a>
```

I've included the main calling html + script for completeness

```
    <style type="text/css"> .SomeClass { background-color: yellow } </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function dump(str) {
            $('<div>' + str + '<br/></div>').appendTo('body');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ba-replacetext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            one();
        });
    </script>
```