# Display $.get result in a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use this code to call the controller when I click on the tab. When I click on the second tab, I clear the second and vice versa. The problem, I can't put the result of my $.get in the div (tabs-1 or tabs-2). I see there is a result (data) with firebug

Any idea ?

```
 $("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
    switch (ui.index) {
        case 0:
            $("#tabs-2").empty();
            $.post("/Controller/Index", { variable1: 1, variable2: 0 },
                function (data) {
                    $("#tabs-1").text(html);
                });
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#tabs-1").empty();
            $.post("/Controller/Index", {  variable1: 2, variable2: 1 },
                function(data){
                    $("#tabs-2").text(html);

            });
            break;
    }
});
```

**Update1 :**
In the "data" result there is an ..... I'd like get the content and display it in tabs-2 as HTML. That's means if there are  I have the see them.

Comment: Your example code is a little messed up. You're passing the response as 'data', but using 'html' to set the content for the DIVs.

Comment: yes yes, I need to sleep :) See the comment in the Jan Zyka answer.

Comment: Could you check update1, at this time I see only charecter and no HTML control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it simply a typo? You are using `$("#tabs-1").text(html);` where the variable `html` doesn't exist. Try `$("#tabs-1").text(data);`.

Comment: haaaaa your are right (data and not HTML)! but the result is not perfect. That return the full code of the page (titrel, header, body ...). In the result there is the <div id="anchor"> .... </div>, I d'like get the content of this <anchor>. How can I do ?

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery Seems it doesn't work in some IE version though. Can't think of better idea in the moment