# Can't use javascript regex to get everything between html/xml tags

Tags: javascript, html, xml, regex, pcre

So I receive some xml in plaintext (and no I can't use DOM or JSON because apparently I am not allowed to), I want to strip all elements encased in a certain element and put them into an array, where I can strip out the text in the individual segments.
Now I am used to using POSIX regex and I will never actually understand the point behind PCRE regex, nor do I get the syntax.

Now here is the code I am using:

```
var strResponse = objResponse.text;
                    var strRegex = new RegExp("<item>(.*?)<\/item>","i");
                    var arrMatches = "";
                    var match;
                    while (match = strRegex.exec(strResponse)) {
                        arrMatches[] = match[1];
                    }
```

I have no idea why it won't find any matches with this code, can someone please help me on this and perhaps elaborate on what exactly it is I am continuously doing wrong with the PCRE syntax?

Comment: *"Can't use javascript regex to get everything between html/xml tags…"* Exactly, you can't use a JavaScript regex to parse html/xml. HTML and XML are not [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and so cannot be parsed reliably with regular expressions. Many have tried. Many have failed. You'll need recursive descent, or a state machine, etc. -- e.g., a proper parser. If it's XML, it'll be a ***lot*** simpler than if it's HTML, which is not well-formed and thus requires dramatically more domain-specific knowledge.

Comment: Separately: You should be getting a syntax error with that code, this `arrMatches[] = match[1];` is invalid. You have to have something within the `[]`. It's not clear what you're using the brackets *for*, as you've assigned a string to `arrMatches`.

Comment: The dot character would be my first suspect but then, without some sample markup, I can't be sure. Can you post some sample markup as well?

Comment: @T.J., yeah I forgot to define it as an array, because I had to just quickly write the last part, to make it give more sense.

Comment: @Kris: Even if you assign an array to the variable, the syntax `arrMatches[] = match[1];` is still incorrect. You need something inside the `[]` on the left. (I think you probably meant either `arrMatches.push(match[1]);` or `arrMatches[arrMatches.length] = match[1];`, both of which will add `match[1]` to the array.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to complete this task is using the following, to parse it as proper HTML and navigate it with the DOM parser:
[Javascript function to parse HTML string into DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130237/javascript-function-to-parse-html-string-into-dom)
Regex has it with being very faulty and is in general not very good for parsing irregular text like HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

If those tags are in different rows the `.` will not match the newline characters and therefor your expression will not match. This is just a guess, I don't know your source.

You can try

```
var strRegex = new RegExp("<item>([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/item>","i");
```

`[\\s\\S]` is a character class. containing all whitespace and all non whitespace characters. linebreaks are covered by the whitespace characters.

Comment: You need to either double your backslashes (as you're using a string), or **much** better, use literal syntax: `var rex = /<item>([\s\S]*?)</\item>/i;` But it's all in vain regardless, you can't use regular expressions as an entire solution to parsing XML or HTML.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I added the backslashes to stick to his code. As the OP wrote he is not able to use a parser, so he knows the difficulties too, I assume. I do.

Comment: He said he couldn't use DOM or JSON (what JSON has to do with it, I'm not sure), he didn't say he couldn't use/write a parser.

Comment: @T.J., as stema said I have absolutely no way of using a parser, DOM is for XML and JSON is for RSS feed requests. In your string, why is the escape after the slash?

@stema, thanks I will try that.

Comment: @Kris: [JSON](http://json.org) isn't for RSS feed requests, it's a general-purpose format. But I don't understand why it's coming up in the context of this question, unless you can change the data you're being given. If you rely purely on regular expressions for this, it's going to be very brittle. If you are allowed to write more than five lines of code, and if the input is XML (not HTML), you can write a simple recursive-descent parser for it.

Comment: @T.J., as I already pointed out, I can't because all external calls are blocked, except if I used the built in functions, which are broken. That is why I need to use regex, because the only remote call that isn't broken, is the one that returns plaintext. And I never said it was for RSS, I just pointed out that the host uses JSON to parse RSS feeds.

Comment: @Kris: *Again*, I'm not suggesting you use anything "external." I'm suggesting that **you** can write a simple recursive-descent parser for XML, which will be dramatically more reliable than trying to use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail. Nothing external, you're either allowed to write code to solve this problem or you're not. It doesn't have to be big, not with XML.

Comment: @T.J., Ahh, like that. Well I am open to suggestions, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Kris: [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent) will get you started. You shouldn't have too much trouble finding examples. "Recursive descent" just means that because elements can be nested, the parser will tend to call itself. You could also use a state machine. I'm curious who it is that won't "allow" you to use the excellent parser built into the browser, though.

Comment: @T.J., Google... They made functions for calls in their API, but they use some sort of homemade, jQuery incompatible piece of junk code. Very unlike Google, which is why I think it might be an abandoned API. Thank you for this, I will look into building my own. If you want, you can check my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593809/google-gadget-not-capable-of-parsing-xml-properly

Comment: @T.J., I found $.parseXML() in jQuery, that does the job, thanks a lot for the idea!

Comment: @Kris: I was about to point you at the bits underlying that (I didn't realize you could use jQuery on your project; this is a place where jQuery isn't actually doing much, just dealing with an IE-ism). I'd recommend posting your own answer saying it turns out you *could* use the DOM parser after all (that's what that's doing) and accepting that.

Comment: @T.J., Yeah I could, but the thing is that the built in DOM parser from Google doesn't work, and I didden't know I could invoke it "manually".