# How to get a selected div portion from a variable containing html code by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have a variable `var 'html'`, it contains some html codes .in it there is a **div** with id `messages`. I want to get only that div contents from the 'html' variable into another variable using javascript.
Please help . .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery

Comment: can you post the content of html variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way with jQuery in my opinion:

```
var message = $('<div />').append(html).find('#message').text();
                                                      //.html();
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's valid HTML, you don't even have to append it to the DOM:

```
var html = "<div id='wrapper'><div id='messages'>Messages!</div></div>";

// Create DOM node (subtree) from the string (but don't append to the document):
var node = $(html);

// Find the messages div:
var messages = node.children('#messages');

// Get the contents of the div:
var result = messages.text();
```

**Edit**: here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xndKN/1/

Comment: Ok in this example i want to get the whole html inside the wrapper.then ?

Comment: To get the whole HTML contents of the wrapper div, just do `var contents = $(html).children('#wrapper').html()`. See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: In my opinion, the accepted answer must be yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// your html code
var html = '...'; 

// add a temporary div
$('<div id="temp" style="display:none">'+html+'</div>').appendTo('body');

// extract the data inside the 'message' div
var message = $('#temp #message').text();

// remove temporary div
$('#temp').remove();
```

Now, the variable `message` will contain the text inside the div with id `'message'`

Comment: OP wants to retrieve data not to insert

Comment: The insertion is temporary and is done just so that we can access it easily via DOM instead of having to parse through the HTML.

Comment: @techfoobar: You don't have to append the HTML to the "live" DOM tree. You can parse it offline: `$('<div />').append(myhtml).find('#message').text();`.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes, the insertion was not needed at all. Realizing it now.. :) Tks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you question is not giving enough information about your situation. You have not posted the code. Anyway if you try the following you will get access the the message div.

```
var o = $("<html><body><div id='parent'><div id='message'>Hello</div></div></body></html>")
$(o).children("#message").text()
```

I have tried it on Chrome Developer tool and it is working.

Comment: There's no need to re-wrap `o` -- you used the `jQuery()` function (or `$()`) to create it, so it's already wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: @PPvg the code mentioned above is just for reference purpose. You are free to use whatever way you like to achieve the same output

Comment: If I offended you: my apologies. I was merely trying to elucidate the use of the jQuery method. This mystical, magical "`$()`" function is not always clear to newcomers to jQuery. While passing a jQuery object to the jQuery function is in no way harmful (jQuery will just return the object unaltered), it's always useful to know what you're doing and why you're doing it the way you are.

Comment: (In fact: if it *were* harmful or even just bad practice, I would have edited your answer.)

Comment: @PPvG: *jQuery will just return the object unaltered*: Depends on what you mean. It will contain the same elements, but it creates a new jQuery object. `o === $(o)` is `false`.

Comment: @PPvG.. No buddy you have not offended me. You were right to point out the use of jQuery(). I apologies for being bit rude while responding to your comment..

Comment: @FelixKling: you're right. I'd just assumed it would leave it untouched. I turns out a new jQuery collection is created and the `prevObject` property is lost. If you use chaining on jQuery objects, you can use `prevObject` to traverse back over the chain. Here's a little experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/aJedH/. I learn something every day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var myhtml = "here is my data outside div
              <div id='message'>inside div with id message</div>";
var node = $(myhtml);
$(node).append(myhtml);

alert($(node).find('div#message').text());
```

#### [`WORKING DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/jedcz/)

Comment: There's no need to append the node to the document; you can traverse DOM nodes even if they're detached from the DOM tree.

Comment: It seems a bit odd to me to append the HTML code to itself. If you think the HTML string is not valid HTML, then I suggest to create an empty div and append the string there: `$('<div />').append(myhtml).find('#message')`. This will always work.