# How to fetch a value from outerHTML using jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

i have an requierement where i need to fetch value from outerHTML using jquery. below is my js function

[image]

where event.outerHTML will contain

```
    <INPUT id=307 onclick=addremoveartifact(this,4); CHECKED type=checkbox flag="false" stkrvwrqrd="" arttype="Other" docId="" ppArtId="1516" appBy="suman.sathyanandam@hp.com" status="Approved">
```

How to fetch the value of "status". some one please help

Comment: The below post will help to solve your problem too.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery

Comment: thanks sundar.. i have gone through it. it's not helping

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a project I was working on. 
This is what I suggest:

`var status = $($(event)[0]).attr('status');`