# jQuery parse HTML string and do some operations on it

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically created HTML string (a table rows). That rows count in that string can be greater than 1.

```
string myHtml = "
            <tr>
               <td class="text-left">
                  <label class="label-none">a.docx</label>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <label class="label-none">Manuscript </label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input class="del-file-cb" file-id="71" type="checkbox" />
               </td>
            </tr>" 
            etc...
```

**Before inserting** it to the DOM element (table) I want to check if inside it exists a checkbox input with the specific value of the `file-id` attribute. If so, I want to change the `text` of the 1st `label` (**in the row where that found checkbox is placed**) to e.g. `lorem`, and the 2nd `label`'s `text` to e.g. `ipsum`. How to do that ?

### Edit

also here are some useful informations [stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var mYdomelement = $('
            <tr>
               <td class="text-left">
                  <label class="label-none">a.docx</label>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <label class="label-none">Manuscript </label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input class="del-file-cb" file-id="71" type="checkbox" />
               </td>
            </tr>');

if(mYdomelement.find(":checkbox").attr("file-id") == "Yourvalue"){
   $("label:first-child", mYdomelement).text('lorem');
   $("label:nth-child(2)", mYdomelement).text('ipsum');
}
```

Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/govindmalviya/QaZYv/1/)

Comment: You might want to escape the double quotes in your attributes.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
if($(#elementId + ' input[file-id|="YOUR_VALUE_HERE"]').length > 0)
{
    $(this).ancestors().eq(2).find('label').eq(0).val(FIRST_LABEL_VALUE_HERE);
    $(this).ancestors().eq(2).find('label').eq(0).val(SECOND_LABEL_VALUE_HERE);
}
```

Comment: it'll search the DOM elements on page, not in my string

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to look for the checkbox inside the DOM, not inside your string