# How to get title tag in a string of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hey i'm loading an html page using ajax into a string, now i want to find the title of the page and use it.

Now i did manage to get the `<title>` using regex but that returns the tag along with the title itself and i wish to extract that from the string or could there be a way to do that in the regex?

This is my code :

```
var title = result.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/);
```

Now how do i get the actuall title after this/ instead of this?

Comment: Use jquery to pick out the title tag... Don't use regex.

Comment: It's inside a string not in the document

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I have seen solution that parses the HTML string and operates on it. EDIT: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery

Comment: I'd be happy if you showed me some link to those solutions, as this could save me alot of time.

Comment: @nhahtdh if you submit as answer, I'd vote it up, and submitter should probably accept it. It is the cleanest way hands down.

Comment: @tucuxi: There is an answer for this already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

load your response html string into a jQuery object like so and retrieve the text

```
$(response).find("title").text();
```

Comment: The document is a response to an ajax request. Hence it may not be accessible via document.title

Comment: this didn't work for me directly for some reason (jQuery 1.9.1), I had to put the response in a div and load that into a jQuery object instead: `var div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = response; $(div).find('title').text();`

Answer (score 18):

`.match()` returns array of matches, use

```
var title = result.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1];
```

to get value in parentheses

Comment: Thank you ivan this did work. But is there some better way to get the title tag?

Comment: if you working with html as string, you can use `/<title>(.*?)</title>/i` regexp. if you use jquery, you can create document fragment and pick value from it `$(yourHtmlString).find('title').text()`

Answer (score 4):

A relatively simple plain-JavaScript, and non-regex, approach:

```
var htmlString = '<head><title>Some title</title></head><body><p>Some text, in a paragraph!</p></body>',
    html = document.createElement('html'),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
html.innerHTML = htmlString;
frag.appendChild(html);

var titleText = frag.firstChild.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent || frag.firstChild.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText;

console.log(titleText);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fJPUm/).

I've, obviously, had to guess at your HTML string and removed the (presumed-present) enclosing `<html>`/`</html>` tags from around the content. However, even if those tags are in the string it still works: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fJPUm/1/).

And a slightly more functional approach:

```
function textFromHTMLString(html, target) {
    if (!html || !target) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            container = document.createElement('div');
        container.innerHTML = html;
        fragment.appendChild(container);
        var targets = fragment.firstChild.getElementsByTagName(target),
            result = [];

        for (var i = 0, len = targets.length; i<len; i++) {
            result.push(targets[i].textContent || targets[i].innerText);
        }
        return result;        
    }
}

var htmlString = '<html><head><title>Some title</title></head><body><p>Some text, in a paragraph!</p></body></html>';

var titleText = textFromHTMLString(htmlString, 'title');

console.log(titleText);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fJPUm/2/).

Comment: Amazing answer, no regex!!! I've been banging my head with substrings and lengths trying to extract first, second, third `img` tags from an html string.  This is so easy now!!!

Answer (score 3):

**CODE:**

```
var title = result.match("<title>(.*?)</title>")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the reg exp to case insensitive.
Here is the complete code:

```
var regex = /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/gi; 
var input = "<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head>...</html>";
if(regex.test(input)) {
  var matches = input.match(regex);
  for(var match in matches) {
    alert(matches[match]);
  } 
} else {
  alert("No matches found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I think this will help. It perfectly works in my case. :)

```
 var FindTag=(data='',tag='')=>{
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML=data;
    data=$(div).find(tag)[0].outerHTML;
    return data;
 }

var data=FindTag(data,"title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't a good way to look for things in HTML, which is too complex for a simple one-off regex. (See the [famous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454) on this topic.) Instead, use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)'s [`parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) and then look in the resulting document:

```js
const html = "<!doctype html><head><title>example</title>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
const title = doc.querySelector("title");
console.log(title.textContent);
```