# How can I fetch whole HTML source code of destination URL, and parse with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming there is a website such as `foo-example.com`
I'd like to fetch the whole HTML source code of the top `index` page (http://foo-example.com/index.html)

And the code for index.html is this:

**HTML SOURCE CODE OF (http://foo-example.com/index.html)**

```
<html>
    <title>Hello, world</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed type="application" id="records" link="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fetch the whole HTML source code, and parse strings that are wrapped by links?
Then I want to to pop up alert like this `alert(strings);` in the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034881/what-is-the-best-practice-for-parsing-remote-content-with-jquery

Comment: Also possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery?lq=1 ?

Comment: The `.load()` function can't do that ??